# How to send a Request to DB using values from Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

So i have a dropdown which gets prefilled (on page load) with sql statement that selects all of my available names.
What i want to do is when i hit the send button it should get back all the data relevant to my selected name. I'm really a noob when i comes to ajax request and i would appreciate your help alot. Right now i get data back but i'm not sure how do "search" for my selected name in the data.
What i have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        let dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('selected_project');

        function getFilteredData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/solid2/filtered_data.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    let name = [];
                    let ertrag = [];
                    let kollektrofläche = [];
                    let jahr = [];
                    let monat = [];
                    for (let i in data) {
                        name.push(data[i].Name);
                        kollektrofläche.push(data[i].Kollektorfläche);
                        ertrag.push(data[i].Ertrag);
                        jahr.push(data[i].Jahr);
                        monat.push(data[i].Monat);
                    }
                    let selectedProjectName = dropdownMenu.options[dropdownMenu.selectedIndex].text;
                    console.log(selectedProjectName);


                    let ctx = document.getElementById('yearly_chart');
                    let yearly_solar_energy = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',

                        // The data for our dataset
                        data: {
                            labels: selectedProjectName,
                            // Information about the dataset
                            datasets: [{
                                label: "Monatliche Solarerträge [kWh/Monat]",
                                backgroundColor: 'orange',
                                borderColor: 'royalblue',
                                data: selectedProjectName
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                })
                }
            });
        }
        function getProjectName() {

        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select  id=selected_project name="selected_project">
        <?php
        include 'get_data.php';
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo "<option value=$row[ID]>$row[Name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <button onclick="getFilteredData()">Send</button>
</div>
    <canvas id="yearly_chart"></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

And here's the filtered_data.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT monitoring_database.systems.display_name AS Name,
monitoring_database.systems.collector_area AS Kollektorfläche,
ROUND(AVG(monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.value))AS Ertrag,
YEAR(monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.timestamp) AS Jahr,
MONTHNAME(monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.timestamp) AS Monat
FROM monitoring_database.systems
INNER JOIN monitoring_database.heat_meter
ON monitoring_database.systems.id = monitoring_database.heat_meter.system_id
INNER JOIN monitoring_database.heat_meter_values
ON monitoring_database.heat_meter.id = monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.heat_meter_id
GROUP BY Name, Jahr
");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Did you write `filtered_data.php` yet? Or is that what you want help with

Comment: Sorry just updated my question and yes i already wrote it :)

Comment: First, get the selected item from the dropdown. Then pass that in your AJAX call, see the `data: {}` param in the jquery manual. Then change the query to only get the one row that matches the key you pass it, then you can return only One row, the one you are interested in :)

Comment: Thanks that did it for me :)